# Apache 2 different port no for different website

Tags: ubuntu, dns, apache2, port

I have installed the ISPConfig in my ubuntu 16. In my existing apache 2, I have already had a website called example.com which is listening to port 80. For ISPConfig (domain will be https://www.example.com:8088), I plan to use port 8088. I tried to update the example-ssl.conf file to support that.

However, when I access the https://www.example.com:8088, it will redirect to https://www.example.com

I would like to ask if there is any problem with my config as I really cannot find out the problem.

Thank you for your help.

example-ssl.conf

```
Listen 80
Listen 8088

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
        <VirtualHost *:443>
                ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
                ServerName example.com
                ServerAlias www.example.com
                DocumentRoot /var/www/html

                ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
                CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined


                #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf

                #   SSL Engine Switch:
                #   Enable/Disable SSL for this virtual host.
                SSLEngine on


                SSLCertificateFile      /etc/ssl/mysite-selfsigned.crt
                SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/mysite-selfsigned.key


                #SSLCACertificatePath /etc/ssl/certs/
                #SSLCACertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl.crt/ca-bundle.crt


                #SSLCARevocationPath /etc/apache2/ssl.crl/
                #SSLCARevocationFile /etc/apache2/ssl.crl/ca-bundle.crl


                #SSLVerifyClient require
                #SSLVerifyDepth  10


                <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
                </FilesMatch>
                <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
                </Directory>
                BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
                nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
                downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

        </VirtualHost>

</IfModule>
```

example.com-8088.conf

```
Listen 8088
<VirtualHost *:8088>
        ServerName example.com:8088
        ServerAlias www.example.com:8088
        DocumentRoot /usr/local/ispconfig/interface/web
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you type " **http://** " your browser interprets that as use **port 80** to find the address shown next.
When you type " **https://** " your browser interprets that as use **port 443** ...".

So, when your CUSTOMERS access your site using "https://...." THEY will be trying to arrive to your site on port 443.

Thus, as long as your external firewall can properly **forward** port 443 incoming traffic to whatever alternate port your server is using, and send its responses back out in a way the customers' browser understands, you'll be fine.

Comment: but I have specify the port no in the URL, e.g. https://www.example.com:8088. isn't it will route to the example-ssl.conf and refer to the documentroot in virtualhost *:8088?

Comment: I think you have to create VHS like this:
'<VirtualHost *:8088>'
Give it a try and let me know.

Comment: sorry for the typo. i changed it but it still routes to the site at port 80.

Comment: @George and you did restart apache after that, right?

Comment: yes. i have created another example.com-8088.conf  (or shall it be example.com-8088-ssl.conf?) for it. apache is restarted but it still routes to port 80 website

Comment: I tried to add the same vhost in default-ssl.conf and it still routes to the port 443 site....

Answer (score 0):

Add the port in `/etc/apache2/ports.conf`, as

```
Listen 8088
```

If you haven't done it already, enable your site with

```
sudo a2ensite example.com-8088.conf
```

And restart Apache

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

You need to add the SSL settings in  `example.com-8088.conf` as well, or access it with http://www.example.com:8088 (not https)

Comment: i disable all the default-ssl.conf and 000-default.conf and it works now... but it's interesting to me that only example.com:8088 is working but www.example.com:8088 will route to www.example.com